# Ошибка при работе с glut

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот такой код который по идее должен работать

```
import OpenGL
import OpenGL.GL
import OpenGL.GLUT
import OpenGL.GLU
print("Imports successful!") 

def showScreen():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) # Remove everything from screen (i.e. displays all white)

glutInit() # Initialize a glut instance which will allow us to customize our window
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA) # Set the display mode to be colored
glutInitWindowSize(500, 500)   # Set the width and height of your window
glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0)   # Set the position at which this windows should appear
wind = glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Coding Practice") # Give your window a title
glutDisplayFunc(showScreen)  # Tell OpenGL to call the showScreen method continuously
glutIdleFunc(showScreen)     # Draw any graphics or shapes in the showScreen function at all times
glutMainLoop()  # Keeps the window created above displaying/running in a loop
```

Но пишет вот эту ошибку

```
NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined function glutInitDisplayMode, check for bool(glutInitDisplayMode) before calling
```

Скорее всего ошибка не в коде, а из за отсутствие каких то файлов

Answer (score 0):

*Удалите* **PyOpenGl**
Скачайте от сюда вашу версию

[pyopengl](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyopengl)

*И установите через* **pip**